# How to execute/return a part of a query based on a result of that query (with Eloquent, or raw SQL)?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, eloquent

I am trying to get the content of a page based on the slug of the page (the identifier), and the set locale/language. However, If the page is not available in the database with the selected locale, I want to return the page with a fall back locale, which should always be available (if it is not, return an error).

For my app I am using Laravel's Eloquent ORM.

Data in the 'pages' table (pseudocode):

```
- entry 1:
    title: About
    slug: about
    locale: en
    content: the content of the about page

- entry 2:
    title: Informatie
    slug: about
    locale: nl
    content: De tekst van de informatie pagina

- entry 3:
    title: Home
    slug: home
    locale: en
    content: The content of the home page
```

Desired output (with fallback locale = en):

```
Required return to set $page to:

if the selected locale = nl, slug = about:
     'entry 2'
if the selected locale = en, slug = about:
     'entry 1'
if the selected locale = nl, slug = home:
     (since the nl-page is not available for this slug)
     set $page to 'entry 3'
```

This is the code I have written:

```
<?php
... other code ...

//based on selection
$slug = 'something';
$locale = 'the selected locale';

//setting for fallback Locale
$fallbackLocale = 'en';

//first try to get the page with the selected locale        
$page = Page::where([
                    'slug' => $slug,
                    'locale' => $locale
                ])
                ->first();

// if the first query is empty, get the page with the fallback Locale
if (empty($page))
{
    $page = Page::where([
                        'slug' => $slug,
                        'locale' => $fallbackLocale
                    ])
                    ->firstOrFail();
}
```

As you can see, this code does work altough I am performing two querys. I would like to perform one query, where it checks if the first half of the query return something (the page with the selected locale), if this is empty, then look for the page with the fall back locale (the slug is still the same).

***Is there a way to do this with Eloquent?*** (I don't think so, the methods with 'if' statements in eloquent are meant to be used to check if a parameter in a form is set, not if a query returns something)

***And if it is not possible with Eloquent, is it possible with just regular SQL?***

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help convey what you are trying to do.

Comment: How do you know one query would be faster? And how slow is it now? Is it impacting performance? You have measured it? You tested using one query for your data? Was it faster? imo, You need to measure it. Without measurements then how can you decide which is better or worse? There is no proof that one query is always or often better than two queries. Why? The first query loads stuff into memory...

Comment: Well, I don't know how to do it with one query, so I am not able to measure it with one query. I think it is generally better to perform only one query then to perform multiple querys, since only one connection needs to be made (altough multiple smaller quers might be faster then one large one).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you select both and order by `locale = 'en'` 'nl' will be selected first because `'nl' = 'en'` is `0` and `'en' = 'en'` is `1`.

```php
$page = Page::where('slug', $slug)
    ->whereIn('locale', [$locale, $fallbackLocale])
    ->orderByRaw("locale = '$fallbackLocale'")
    ->first();
```

The problem here: If `$fallbackLocale` comes from user input, it is not injection save. And i didn't find a way to use a placeholder in the `orderByRaw()` caluse.

But you can use a raw query with placeholders:

```php
$page = Page::hydrateRaw("
        select *
        from pages
        where slug = ?
          and locale in (?, ?)
        order by locale = ?
        limit 1
    ",
    [$slug, $locale, $fallbackLocale, $fallbackLocale]
)->first();
```

**Update:**

I've found a way to use a placeholder in `orderByRaw()`:

```php
$page = Page::where('slug', $slug)
    ->whereIn('locale', [$locale, $fallbackLocale])
    ->orderByRaw("locale = ?")
    ->addBinding($fallbackLocale, 'order')
    ->first();
```

Comment: I do like your way of thinking. Altough when I implement the first method it gives me an error that it does not know the 'en' column:  SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'en' in 'order clause' (SQL: select * from `pages` where `slug` = home and `locale` in (nl, en) order by `locale` = en)

Comment: @FeatherNL - Fixed that. But you should not use the first solution as it is, unless you find a way to use a placeholder.